# The first menu item(s) redirect to HOME (index.php)

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item

The first menu-item(s) keep redirecting to HOME instead of the article it is supposed to link to.
If I copy the menu item and move it to the end of the menu list, it works ok and displays the right article. If I move another menu item to be the first menu item after Home, it again redirects me to Home. And in the url I see index.php as in the homepage.
So it is not a problem with the article, but with the menu or menu item position.

Have a look at [www.studiolidachaulet.nl/geldmaaktublij.nl](http://www.studiolidachaulet.nl/geldmaaktublij.nl/)

The copy of **Hoe werkt het** for instance, **Hoe werkt het? (2)** works fine, 
But if you click **Hoe werkt het?** it redirects to http://www.studiolidachaulet.nl/geldmaaktublij.nl/index.php

- I have set the SEO settings in Global configuration to YES, YES, NO, NO, after
- .htaccess is not a txt file
- RewriteEngine On

If I change SEO settings to NO, I see the friendly urls change to unfriendly urls but the problem of the first menu item(s) stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
The logo area seemed to overlap part of the menu. I shortened the names and the problem is gone.
Thank you Seth for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some info about your menu structure? Crucially, what menu item type is the menu item you are having trouble with?

As the link to the same article in your footer menu works correctly, this may be a problem with item type alias. Do you have 2 different menus? You shouldn't, as both contain the same links.

Comment: Thanks, all menu item types are individual article. I just have this menu you see. I have never had another menu either. I had not even checked the footer links. I just tried disabling the footer links, but that does not solve the problem. I also changed the alias to hoewerkthet, but that did not solve it either.

Comment: Sounds like the menu item alias is the same for your homepage and your problem article. Delete the existing menu item alias' and save the menu items, Joomla will re-create non-conflicting alias' for you.

Comment: I have done that, no change... Also, I now moved a last menu item forward, and now the "Over ons" does not work and the "Hoe werkt het" does. So it has to do with the menu position... weird.

Comment: Another thing... if you keep clicking, eventually it will open the right link one time and the next time you try it won't.

Comment: Something else... if I switch to another template, the problem is gone. If I just assign the home page to my wanted template, there is a problem going from left to right. But if I click menu items from right to left (test template to wanted template) the problem appears again.